# What is necessary to confirm business ownership and income for UK visa application?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image: Business Confirmation Letter*emphasized text*]

How can a business confirmation letter be written if person is owns the business? What are the sources required if I already provided information that it's the business inward cash sales transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, independent and verifiable evidence such as tax returns, trading accounts prepared by a chartered accountant, invoices /receipts. Anything ‘self-prepared’ is very unlikely to be acceptable.

Comment: But Business confirmation letter is always self written many friends have got the visas who are like me enterprenur

Comment: Sorry but I’m struggling to imagine what a self-written ‘business confirmation letter’ could possibly contain that wouldn’t be better explained in the application itself and by providing suitable, verifiable, evidence.

Comment: E.g detailed info about business activities and info like business start date total income expenditure owner declartion etc

Comment: @Mian Kashif It’s obviously of little value without independent corroborating evidence, or the ECO would have accepted it at face value rather than refusing your application

Comment: Independent corroborating evidence includes how many possible documents and if you can please elaborate in detail.